# I get an empty list when printing multiple elements by class

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to have a list of all of the '_7Uhw9...' classes, despite there being multiple of these classes, spans in them and everything, it prints out an empty list. Why?

```
message_response = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_7UhW9   xLCgt      MMzan  KV-D4         p1tLr      hjZTB')

print(message_response)
```

If you wanna get up close and personal with the HTML you can go to any Instagram account's dm inbox, it should be there. But here is a picture if that's all you need: [Picture of HTML element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkB2N.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**class name separated by space indicates multiple classes**

by_class uses css class notation under the hood , so if it has multiple classes  you should replace space with '.'

```
message_response = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_7UhW9.xLCgt.MMzan.KV-D4.p1tLr.hjZTB')
```

**Else you can use css or xpath attribute check instead:**

here we see class as just attribute and uses below syntax:

syntax for xpath and css are like

**xpath:**

```
//tagname[@attribute="value"]
```

**css**

```
tagname[attribute="value"]
```

**so use any of this syntax**

```
 message_response = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='_7UhW9   xLCgt      MMzan  KV-D4         p1tLr      hjZTB']")
```

or

```
message_response = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[class='_7UhW9   xLCgt      MMzan  KV-D4         p1tLr      hjZTB']")
```

Comment: you said "class name separated by space indicates multiple classes". Does that mean no spaces regardless of whether the class name has spaces or not?